# Why can't I use the ConstaintLayout attributes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

So I'm trying to use the `ConstraintLayout` for the first time.  And I can't use the ConstraintLayout attributes such as `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` to position it's children.

The code doesn't compile when I try to use the attributes either.  It will compile if I use a `ConstraintLayout` but none of it's attributs. What should I do to access those attributes?

The build error I get is

```
error: not well-formed (invalid token).
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: not well-formed (invalid token)., sources= 
[C:\AndroidWorkSource\SalesRabbit-Android\Universal- 
Sales\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_routeitem_list.xml:48], original 
message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

Here is the xml layout in question:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white">

    . . . . 

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_routs_list"
        android:name="com.salesrabbit.android.sales.universal.canvass.routeing.MyRouteFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context=".canvass.routeing.MyRouteFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_routeitem"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_routes_divider"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf ="id/my_routs_list"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/caret"
            android:text="@string/my_routs_new_route"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />
    </LinearLayout>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the build file I have this:

```
dependencies { 
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    . . . . .
```

Comment: What does the logcat return after trying to compile?

Comment: @jle error: not well-formed (invalid token).
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: not well-formed (invalid token)., sources=[C:\AndroidWorkSource\SalesRabbit-Android\Universal-Sales\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_routeitem_list.xml:48], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

Comment: Which line would be line 48 in your fragment_routeitem_list.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf ="id/my_routs_list"
```

you have a weird whitespace character called `HAIR SPACE` (`U+200A`) before the `=` that is causing the XML to be misformed. Deleting it and adding an `@` before the id should solve your problem:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/my_routs_list"
```

Comment: Wow,  I didn't even know HairSpace characters existed.  Thank you so much!